# How to write a custom constraint in the heat template of openstack?

Tags: openstack, heat

I find I can write anything,like this
constraints:
      - custom_constraint:here anything
        description: Value must be one of m1.medium, m1.large or m1.xlarge
and in CLI do this WILL BE OK -> heat template-validate -f bad.yaml

And in the document ,just tell you that's a plugin,how should i write a validation plugin????

Comment: I have find in the heat's tests folder,there is a file called hot_test.py

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `setup.cfg` file in the heat source code you will find there is a section that lists the constraints:

```
heat.constraints =
     nova.flavor = heat.engine.clients.os.nova:FlavorConstraint
     nova.network = heat.engine.clients.os.nova:NetworkConstraint
     ...
```

These reference classes: so if you look at the `FlavorConstraint`, you will find it in the file heat/heat/engine/clients/os/nova.py

An examination of the class should give you an idea of how to write your own.

That is, if I'm understanding your question (and the code!) correctly.